# Using android locksreen pin for authentication

Tags: android, authentication

I am writing an application which needs fingerprint/pin authentication. There were many information about how to use fingerprint authentication in app, however i could not find any information about authentication using pin instead of fingerprint.

Comment: This is in consideration of a topic called Data Classification, specifically of Personally Identifiable Information "PII". Authenticating with a lock-screen pin or any other sort of pattern or sequence does not uniquely identify a person of any sorts wherein a fingerprint does. Hope this makes sense and at least expresses why / where obstacles exist in your use-case.

Comment: Yes, it totally makes sense. However i can not make decisions about functionalities, so I have to figure out if it is even possible to achieve this.